# Pyright can't see Poetry dependencies

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry, pyright

In a poetry project the local dependencies are installed in the `~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/` folder.
Pyright in nvim is complaining that `import` package lines can't be resolved.
What should I include into `pyproject.toml`? Or how to show pyright the path to the dependencies?
Thanks

My `pyrightconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "venvPath": ". /home/ajanb/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/",
    "venv": "tools-configfactory-materialmodel-jnEEQvIP-py3.10"
}
```

I found that I need to add this to the config file of neovim, can you help me to write it in .lua?

```
  au FileType python let b:coc_root_patterns = ['.git', '.env', 'venv', '.venv', 'setup.cfg', 'setup.py', 'pyrightconfig.json']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent days troubleshooting this. In the end, the only thing that worked was including this in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pyright]
venvPath = "/Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs"
venv = "bfrl-93mGb6aN-py3.11"
```

I'm also using this nvim plugin: [poet-v](https://github.com/petobens/poet-v)

I guess you could accomplish this through a proper LSP configuration, but I was just not familiar enough with lua and the lsp configuration to tackle that automatically.

Comment: For future readers, you can find out the correct venvPath and which venv you're using by typing running the command: poetry show -v

Comment: With this approach you are hard-coding `venv` with a value that is specific to your environment (your localhost). This is not ideal, if you share your code, or intend to run it in other environments. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76447838/748139) by @kevin-roadie is superior in the sense that the configured values are independent from any specific environment. I recommend using Kevin's approach.

Comment: Can't you activate poetry's venv in the shell before running pyright?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Poetry, then the following shell snippet will create the file for you:

```bash
    jq \
      --null-input \
      --arg venv "$(basename $(poetry env info -p))" \
      --arg venvPath "$(dirname $(poetry env info -p))" \
      '{ "venv": $venv, "venvPath": $venvPath }' \
      > pyrightconfig.json
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved this issue. Inside my pyproject.toml, I configured pyright like this (among other things):

```
[tool.pyright]
venvPath = "."
venv = ".venv"
```

Then I included a poetry.toml in my project with this:

```
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

This way I don't have to discover the path and name of my virtual env, its always the same and available in-project.